# only a single css section not working in deployed application compared to local host

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently done a upgrade to `heroku-18` from `heroku-16`. As a part of it I had to upgrade by ruby and rails. Ruby from `2.3.3` to `2.4.5` and Rails from `4.2.0` to `4.2.10`. After doing that the application is working fine in local system. but when I deployed one section in view is missing. when i inspect the code from browser, the `<div> class="product"></div>` doesn't have anything. it looks empty. This is my code

```
/new.html.erb
.
.
<div class="products" >
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-sm-3 cart">
      <%= render "product_cart", product: product, order: @order %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
.
.



/_product_cart.html.erb
.
.
<div class="product-card">
<%= simple_form_for order do |form| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "product[id][]", product.id %><br>
<div class="name"><%= "#{product.name}" %></div>
<div class="price"><%= format_currency(product.price_cents) %></div>
<div class="description"><%= product.description %></div>
<%= submit_tag "Buy Now", class: "btn paypal-btn" %>
<% if product.name == "Business" %>
  <div class="most-popular">Most Popular</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Only this section is not working. Rest every part is working fine. Can somebody please help me on this. Am I missing something as a part of my upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Try to like this using `locals`

```
<%= render partial: 'product_cart', locals: {product: product, order: @order } %>
```

and in the form add `form` object to input field as like

```
form.hidden_field
form.submit
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After an analysis, I found out that the data in table _product_ is missing in heroku. May I know how can I add that data back into heroku database from local database?